# Custom Search API - quotas and pricing

Tags: google-api

I understand a CSE provides 100 free searches per day, but have read conflicting information on the following two points.

For each request whether it is free or paid, are the search results limited?

For when the daily limit of 100 searches is reached, I understand I will be billed an additional $5 for a block of 1,000 more searches. Are these additional searches lost the following day if they are not used?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just pay a fraction.

Like if you only search 100 extra, this will cost $0.50